# Revise my keyword but still cannot login

Tags: password

It is unluky that I lost my wordpress password,so I update it with mysql command  .

```
    UPDATE wp_users SET user_pass = MD5('hello') WHERE id=1;

    mysql> select * from wp_users;
+----+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| ID | user_login                       | user_pass                        | user_nicename | user_email          | user_url | user_registered     | user_activation_key                | user_status | display_name |
+----+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
|  1 | 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592 | 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592 | luofeiyu      | haha@haha.com |          | 2015-02-16 13:24:31 | $P$BdoVxdl8z6/8fhBmumk0vuMdlDsARz. |           0 | luofeiyu     |
+----+----------------------------------+----------------------------------+---------------+---------------------+----------+---------------------+------------------------------------+-------------+--------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now ,why I can't login with username "luofeiyu" and password "hello" in my wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You somehow changed `user_login` to your password hash.

`user_login` should be `luofeiyu`